# Email account won't sign in

Tags: pantheon-mail

I cannot figure out what is happening in pantheon mail. On first time opening, I try to enter my email but it says "incorrect username or password" everytime. But if I go to Gmail online it works perfectly fine. What do I do?

Comment: Do you have Googles security verification step enabled?

Comment: Do I want it enabled? And where would I change that?

Comment: I'd disable it just to reduce variables.  It does keep some apps from working.  https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?hl=en

Comment: The two step verification is not enabled.

Comment: Yea, It's off and it still isn't working. Any other suggestions? I can sign in on Thunderbird as well.

Comment: One more thing. Try enabling less secure apps. If that doesn't work, a little more information could help. Are you on Freya or Loki and what version number is your mail app?  https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: The less secure apps was the problem. Thank you so much!